Why doesn't increasing shots improve results using gate-cutting from Qiskit circuit knitting toolbox?
I am trying to understand the Qiskit Circuit Knitting Toolbox 0.7.2 . I implemented the sample problem for gate cutting in particular. In my understanding if we increase the number of shots the reconstructed results should improve. But I find that this is not true. Is there a reason for this?
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import SamplerV2, Batch

# Set up the Qiskit Runtime Sampler primitive
sampler = SamplerV2(backend=backend)

for ii in np.arange(10,20):
    # Submit each partition's subexperiments as a single batch
    with Batch(backend=backend):
        jobs = {
            label: sampler.run(subsystem_subexpts, shots=2**ii)
            for label, subsystem_subexpts in isa_subexperiments.items()
        }

    # Retrieve results
    results = {label: job.result() for label, job in jobs.items()}

    from circuit_knitting.cutting import reconstruct_expectation_values

    # Get expectation values for each observable term
    reconstructed_expvals = reconstruct_expectation_values(
        results,
        coefficients,
        subobservables,
    )

    # Reconstruct final expectation value
    final_expval = np.dot(reconstructed_expvals, observable.coeffs)

    from qiskit_aer.primitives import EstimatorV2

    estimator = EstimatorV2()
    exact_expval = estimator.run([(qc, observable)]).result()[0].data.evs
    print(f"Reconstructed expectation value: {np.real(np.round(final_expval, 8))}")
    print(f"Exact expectation value: {np.round(exact_expval, 8)}")
    print(f"Error in estimation: {np.real(np.round(final_expval-exact_expval, 8))}")
    print(
        f"Relative error in estimation: {np.real(np.round((final_expval-exact_expval) / exact_expval, 8))}"
    )
    

